# Excel VBA userform to Select Outlook folder to copy from

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to create a user form that will allow the user to select the folder to copy a set of emails from to an excel spreadsheet. I have done all the rest (ie created the copy process) but currently I have to manually enter the namespace and folder hierarchy for each new installation of this macro. Below is my manual process

```
Set ol_App = New Outlook.Application
Set ol_Namespace = ol_App.GetNamespace("MAPI")
' Set ol_Folder = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

' reference the folder that the emails are stored in
Set ol_Folder = ol_Namespace.Folders("Their own namespace")
Set ol_Folder = ol_Folder.Folders("Inbox")
Set ol_Folder = ol_Folder.Folders("Required_Folder")
```

Now this vba will be shared among a fair few people and each person has a different setup. Is there a way I can set this up in a userform using say a list-box and all they do is select the correct folder and click continue and the folder selection is stored in a variable or some sort?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? This will also negate the need to use a listbox. :)

```
Option Explicit

'~~> Set a reference to Outlook Object x.x Library
Sub Sample()
    Dim oOlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNmSpc As Namespace
    Dim ofldr As Object

    Set oOlApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNmSpc = oOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set ofldr = objNmSpc.PickFolder

    If Not ofldr Is Nothing Then MsgBox ofldr
End Sub
```

And here is via Late Binding i.e, if you do not want to add the reference to Outlook Object x.x Library

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim oOlApp As Object, objNmSpc As Object, ofldr As Object

    '~~> Establish an Outlook application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oOlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set objNmSpc = oOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set ofldr = objNmSpc.PickFolder

    If Not ofldr Is Nothing Then MsgBox ofldr
End Sub
```

**EDIT**:

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: This solves the issue, could I tweak the "Select Folder" to read "Select Folder to Copy From"?

Comment: No. I don't think so. That is an inbuilt Outlook Dialog Box :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is loop through the Outlook Folders and have each Folder name populate the listbox /combobox in the activate event of the form. By doing that, as each person runs it, their own Outlook configuration will be what is used.

This link should give a good start [Outlook Folder Loop](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=76159)